# Array.join inserts extra characters when joining strings created with String.fromCharCode

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, fromcharcode

I have an array of bytes that I would to to encode to a string to pass to `btoa` in the browser.  These bytes use the full 0-255 range.  I encountered what at first seemed to be a bug with `btoa`, but it turns out to be a bug (or at least quite unexpected behavior) with javascript's Array.prototype.join.  To illustrate the problem, I'll start with some base64-encoded data:

```
gACJNqQ0cg==
```

This can be decoded to a byte array as follows:

```
atob('gACJNqQ0cg==').split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
> [128, 0, 137, 54, 164, 52, 114]
```

Now, you would expect to be able to reverse the operation and get back the original string:

```
btoa([128, 0, 137, 54, 164, 52, 114].map(String.fromCharCode).join(''))
```

But instead, you get a much larger string:

```
gAAAAAEAiQIANgMApAQANAUAcgYA
```

Upon further investigation, the problem occurs when joining any strings created with String.fromCharCode:

```
'Hi'.split('').join('').length
> 2
'Hi'.split('').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
> [72, 105]
[72, 105].map(String.fromCharCode).join('').length
> 6
//what?
```

I see this behavior everywhere I have tried it: Chrome (60), Firefox (53), and Node (6.9.4).  In the browser, you don't have simple alternatives such as node's
`new Buffer(array, 'binary').toString('base64')` to work around this problem.  How can I safely create a string from an array of byte values, which can be passed to `btoa`?

Comment: `String.fromCharCode` is being called with multiple arguments (because `map` works that way), that's why you are getting different results.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me if you specify an arrow function in `map` instead of directly passing the `String.fromCharCode` method to it:

```js
console.log(btoa([128, 0, 137, 54, 164, 52, 114].map(x => String.fromCharCode(x)).join('')));
```

Comment: With ES6, you can use the spread syntax: `String.fromCharCode(...theArray)`

Comment: Oh, of course!  String.fromCharCode takes multiple parameters, and can return a string of multiple characters, so the index was being passed in.  I feel dumb now.  It's going to take some restraint not to delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple workaround to this complicated problem:  String concatenation.  Here's an example:

```
let str = '';
[128, 0, 137, 54, 164, 52, 114].forEach(c => {
    str += String.fromCharCode(c);
});

str.length
> 7
btoa(str)
> 
).join('').length
```

It works, and it should perform well enough for strings that aren't huge.  But I would love to see a better, cleaner, solution, or even just to understand more fully what's going on here with String.fromCharCode and Array.prototype.join.